# Customize command prompt globally

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10

I am customizing the Windows 10 Command Prompt using the following method:

Windows key => Type cmd => Open cmd => Right click window => Properties

The problem is that this customization will not stick when the command prompt is opened by other programs.

For example, the Visual Studio's prompt, or the Haskell Platform's *ghci.exe*.

What I customize:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9LAc1gr.png]

What it looks when the prompt is opened by other programs:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rQpEhaD.png]

Comment: Did you try right click > defaults? Properties only changes the current window ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This customization will not stick when the command prompt is opened by other programs.

You are using:

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> > Type "cmd" > Click "cmd" > Right click cmd window titlebar > Select "Properties"

You need to use "Defaults", modifying "Properties" only changes the current window.

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> > Type "cmd" > Click "cmd" > Right click cmd window titlebar > Select "Defaults"